# How can ASP.Net count the number of unread emails in your inbox on Exchange 2013?

Tags: asp.net, graph, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to make an ASP.Net website that will trend and graph the daily totals of emails that go to a certain email address. I do not need to download or process the messages, just return a total number of emails in the inbox for each day.

All of the programming questions I see are for WinForms and use Outlook to count a local PST file, not much out there on ASP.Net working with exchange.

I have found EWS XML elements > UnreadCount but am having difficultly using that element.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa580965(v=exchg.150).aspx

The program code I started playing with to get something to work on the desktop, however I'd hate to leave this as a desktop service and waste the resources and give up on this challenge.

```
' Create Application class and get namespace
Dim outlook As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.ApplicationClass()
Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace = outlook.GetNamespace("Mapi")

Dim _missing As Object = Type.Missing
ns.Logon(_missing, _missing, False, True)

' Get Inbox information in objec of type MAPIFolder
Dim inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)

' Unread emails
Dim unread As Integer = inbox.UnReadItemCount

' Display the subject of emails in the Inbox folder
For Each mail As Outlook.MailItem In inbox.Items
    Console.WriteLine(Wmail.Subject)
Next mail
```

Comment: You use flags, when you read an e-mail, you set the flag that have been readed, then you count the flags.

Answer (score 2):

The `Outlook` Namespace requires Outlook, use the [EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) instead.

The code below will collect the list of emails received in the inbox today.

```
Using Service = New ExchangeService()
    Dim View As New ItemView(Integer.MaxValue)
    Dim sfc As New SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection()

    ' Return only emails received from midnight this morning
    sfc.Add(New SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeReceived, DateTime.Now.Day))

    ' Get the count 
    Dim totalCount = Service.FindItems(f.Id, sfc, View).TotalCount
End Using
```

You may need to look at [EWS Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) to read each mailbox.